Pandas get summation only on required cell of a columns
I have following table with "Rank" & "rice" columns as dataframe in pandas.
I want to have a sum in outcome col on the first positive rice col number. Also ignore the sum if current rice col is positive & above that is also positive.
Outcome col is the outcome which is needed.
Rank    rice    Outcome
------------------------
 1.00   -41.05  
 2.00   763.1   722.05
 3.00   -702.1  
 4.00   -96.35  
 5.00   -670.1  
 6.00   -699.6  
 7.00   -642.1  
 8.00   -31.05  
 9.00   -69.15  
 10.00  -49.15  
 11.00  -539.3  
 12.00  -30.35  
 13.00  -530.1  
 14.00  569.1   -133
 15.00  -600.1  
 16.00  601.1   1
 17.00  620.1   
 18.00  -46.65  
 19.00  -615.2  
 20.00  -581.8  
 21.00  -562.8  
 22.00  538.2   491.55
 23.00  79.85   
 24.00  -582.3  
 25.00  -615.1  
 26.00  22.85   102.7
 27.00  -583.5  
 28.00  -578.1  

I am using following code.
import pandas as pd


data = [['1',-41.05],['2',763.1],['3',-702.1],['4',-96.35],['5',-670.1],['6',-699.6],['7',-642.1],['8',-31.05],['9',-69.15],['10',-49.15],['11',-539.3],['12',-30.35],['13',-530.1],['14',569.1],['15',-600.1],['16',601.1],['17',620.1],['18',-46.65],['19',-615.2],['20',-581.8],['21',-562.8],['22',538.2],['23',79.85],['24',-582.3],['25',-615.1],['26',22.85],['27',-583.5],['28',-578.1]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Rank', 'rice'])
df.loc[df['rice'] >0 , 'outcome'] = df['rice']-df['rice'].shift()

However the outcome is not as per the desired outcome col. Please help.

How do you compute -133?

Its 569.1-702.1

There is something not logic in either 491.55 or 102.7.
Anyway, you could use custom groups/mask and groupby.transform. I'm providing two alternatives (if you want to ignore or not the successive positive values):
m = df['rice'].gt(0)
m2 = (m&~m.shift(fill_value=False))
df.loc[m2, 'Outcome'] = (df['rice']
   #.mask(m&~m2)
   .groupby(m2[::-1].cumsum())
   .transform('first').add(df['rice'])
)

Output (Outcome2 is with the uncommented .mask(m&~m2)):
   Rank    rice  Outcome  Outcome2
0     1  -41.05      NaN       NaN
1     2  763.10   722.05    722.05
2     3 -702.10      NaN       NaN
3     4  -96.35      NaN       NaN
4     5 -670.10      NaN       NaN
5     6 -699.60      NaN       NaN
6     7 -642.10      NaN       NaN
7     8  -31.05      NaN       NaN
8     9  -69.15      NaN       NaN
9    10  -49.15      NaN       NaN
10   11 -539.30      NaN       NaN
11   12  -30.35      NaN       NaN
12   13 -530.10      NaN       NaN
13   14  569.10  -133.00   -133.00
14   15 -600.10      NaN       NaN
15   16  601.10     1.00      1.00
16   17  620.10      NaN       NaN
17   18  -46.65      NaN       NaN
18   19 -615.20      NaN       NaN
19   20 -581.80      NaN       NaN
20   21 -562.80      NaN       NaN
21   22  538.20  1158.30    491.55
22   23   79.85      NaN       NaN
23   24 -582.30      NaN       NaN
24   25 -615.10      NaN       NaN
25   26   22.85   102.70   -559.45
26   27 -583.50      NaN       NaN
27   28 -578.10      NaN       NaN

If you want to avoid having a double value if the first row is positive:
m = df['rice'].gt(0)
m2 = (m&~m.shift(fill_value=False))

g = (df['rice']
   .mask(m&~m2)
   .groupby(m2[::-1].cumsum())
)

df.loc[m2, 'Outcome'] = (g.transform('first')
                          .mask(g.transform('size').eq(1), 0)
                          .add(df['rice'])
                        )

Example (with row 0 removed):
    Rank    rice  Outcome
1      2  763.10   763.10
2      3 -702.10      NaN
3      4  -96.35      NaN
4      5 -670.10      NaN
5      6 -699.60      NaN
6      7 -642.10      NaN
7      8  -31.05      NaN
8      9  -69.15      NaN
9     10  -49.15      NaN
10    11 -539.30      NaN
11    12  -30.35      NaN
12    13 -530.10      NaN
13    14  569.10  -133.00
14    15 -600.10      NaN
15    16  601.10     1.00
16    17  620.10      NaN
17    18  -46.65      NaN
18    19 -615.20      NaN
19    20 -581.80      NaN
20    21 -562.80      NaN
21    22  538.20   491.55
22    23   79.85      NaN
23    24 -582.30      NaN
24    25 -615.10      NaN
25    26   22.85  -559.45
26    27 -583.50      NaN
27    28 -578.10      NaN


I needed the outcome 2 col, My outcome col was wrong. your outcome col is correct

When the Data starts from Positive number, outcome multiplies the the starting positive number with 2. may be it is adding the positive number with the same positive number. How to resolve that? Rest works well.

@rakesh see update
